# Pure Ruby on Rails file uploader, GET issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I've recently started trying to build a file uploader on Rails. I did some searching on stack and via one answer found this [tutorial](http://mattberther.com/2007/10/19/uploading-files-to-a-database-using-rails).  I attempted to build from it; however, I'm only receiving GET request errors when I try to go to my uploader page:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/uploads"
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

I raked routes, and from what I understand, my routes.rb should look something like this:

> PicsUploadr::Application.routes.draw do
>
> > resources :uploads (:html)

However, I'm not 100% sure if that is correct.  I have my controller pointing to the html.erb that I want loaded.  Can anyone point me to where I might be going wrong?

I have the full source up on [github](https://github.com/habutai/pics_uploadr) if anyone cares to look at it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the (:html) bit, the format has nothing to do with the route, at least I don't think so.

Second, your code isn't actually up on that repo, so please run <code>rake routes</code> and paste that here.  Also, please post the form that is making the request.

Comment: You've linked to an empty github repository, FYI.

Comment: sorry, it should be there now--first time using git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well first things first. I would not be using a tutorial from 2007 all of that code is horribly outdated. When googling for a RoR tutorial, try to prefix your searches with the rails version you are using so that the code works correctly.

I would recommend reading the [tutorials here on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

I would also recommend reading up on [Rails Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [RESTful web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) so you can try and make sure your Rails app adheres to those in some way. It will make things easier for you.

At this point I would suggest starting a new project and look into using paperclip or carrierwave after reading about [uploads in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

Answer (score 1):

Jen,

The tutorial you are using is woefully out of date.  I think its best if you got your hands on something like this: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book to get you started.  There are simply too many problems with this app to start explaining them all in here.  Follow the tutorial and you will get to where you want to be with this app!

Joe